# Prove that $p(X,Y)\mapsto p(i,-i)$'s kernel is the ideal $(X+Y,X^2+1)$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

I want to show that $I=(X+Y,X^2+1)\in R=\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$ is a prime ideal. Since $I$ a prime ideal is equivalent to $R/I$ an integral domain, I want to create a homomorphism $\phi: R \to \mathbb{C}$ given by $\phi: p(X,Y)\mapsto p(i,-i)$. This is a surjective homomorphism, so by the first isomorphism theorem we have that $R/\ker(\phi)$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ and since $\mathbb{C}$ is an integral domain, $R/\ker(\phi)$ is an integral domain, so $\ker(\phi)$ is a prime ideal.

So what's left to show is that $\ker(\phi)=I$.

Since $\phi(X+Y)=i+(-i)=0$, and $\phi(X^2+1)=i^2+1=-1+1=0$, we have that $I\subset\ker(\phi)$. I now want to show that no other elements but elements of $I$ are in the kernel, but I don't understand the following proof:

> Suppose $p(X,Y)\in\ker(\phi)$, in other words, $p(i,-i)=0$. This implies that the polynomial $P(X,-X)$ evaluated at $X=i$ is zero and so $p(X,-X)$ is divisible by $X^2+1$. So $P(X,-X)=(X^2+1)Q(X)$ for some $Q\in\mathbb{R}[X]$. Furthermore, $p(X,Y)-p(X,-X)$ is divisble by $Y-(-X)=Y+X$ in $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$. Hence $p(X,Y)=p(X,-X)+(Y+X)T(X,Y)=(X^2+1)Q(X)+(Y+X)T(X,Y)$. So $p(X,Y)\in(X+Y,X^2+1)$.

**I don't understand** why $p(i,-i)=0$ implies $p(X,-X)$ evaluated at $X=i$ equals zero (we just fill in the $i$'s?), nor why it then would be divisible by $X^2+1$.

**I also don't understand** the part starting from "Furthermore". Like why we use that subtraction, or what that means, and why it would be divisible by $Y-(-X)$. Also what is $T(X,Y)$, an equivalent of $Q$?

Comment: Note that $P (X,-X) $ is a polynomial in $X $. So we can write $P (X,-X)=F (X)$. Now $i $ is a root of $F (X) $ as $P (i, -i)=0$. Since $x^2+1$ is the minimal polynomial of $i $ over $\Bbb R $, $x^2+1$ divides $F (X) $.

Comment: Writing out $P (X,Y )-P (X,-X)$ for smaller degree polynomials will be useful to understand the statement about divisibility by $Y+X $.

Comment: Why does $P(i,-i)=0$ mean that $i$ is a root of $F(X)$? Which one do you fill in, $i$ or $-i$ into $F(X)$?

Comment: @ThomasShelby And what do you mean by minimal polynomial "of i over $\mathbb{R}$"? And how does that make $x^2+1$ divide $F(X)$?

Comment: Minimal polynomial of $\alpha $ over some field $K $ is the unique monic irreducible polynomial, say $m (X) $, in $K[X] $ which has $\alpha $ has a root. A polynomial  $f (X)\in K[X] $ has $\alpha $ as a root if and only if $m (X) $ divides  $f (X) $.

Comment: Also note that  $F (i)=P (i,-i)=0$.

Comment: In your case, you only need to prove that if $i $ is a root of a polynomial $f(X) $ in $\Bbb R[X]$, then $X^2+1$ divides $f (X) $. This can be easily proved by using Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: @ThomasShelby I think I get all of it now. For $P(X,Y)-P(X,-X)$ we have by filling in $X=i$ and $Y=-i$ that this expression is zero. So if we find a minimal polynomial of $i$ over the field $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$, this polynomial divides $P(X,Y)-P(X,-X)$. A polynomial of degree 0 would have to be the constant monic polynomial $1$ of which $i$ is not a root. So then we look at polynomials of degree 1. An easy one $X+Y$ yields $i+-i=0$, so this is our monic polynomial of least degree. Therefore $P(X,Y)-P(X,-X)$ is divisble by $X+Y$.

Comment: See this [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1173079/zeros-in-the-polynomial-ring-mathbbr-x-y?rq=1).